# Using starts-with twice issue - not working to find HREF

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I answered a question recently.  How come on https://stackoverflow.com/ the Hot Networks question Tab:

If you use:

`//a[starts-with(@href, ('https://stackexchange.com/questions'))]` works fine.

However, when I try to use starts-with or contains twice and it does not seem to work

```
.//a[starts-with(@href, "https://stackexchange.com/questions")][starts-with(@Class, 'js-gps-track')
```

Comment: in chrome, does the xpath returns any matching node?

Comment: @santhoshkumar  .//a[starts-with(@href, "https://stackexchange.com/questions")]  works